# Elasticsearch does not automatically add schema for unknown fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

When Elasticsearch does automatically add schema for unknown/dynamic fields?

```
"fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [dynamic field mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html) and this is enabled by default.

You can disable that feature if necessary.

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604579/val - Actually its not adding automatically when using elastic search 7.10 with hibernate Search 6

But before it was working or adding dynamic mapping for unknown fields when we were using elastic search 6.8 and hibernate-search 5.  any reason??

Comment: This has always been enabled by default in ES. So probably that Hibernate Search 5 and 6 have a different configuration of this setting.